# Find and replace when run as macro changes date value

Tags: date, excel, vba

I am having some trouble with find and replace. In my source workbook, I have text strings of project start dates. They read the first three letters of each day (Mon-Fri) then the associated date "Mon dd/mm/yyyy" for example. I need them in the form of dates "dd/mm/yyyy" so that I can use them after extraction in another workbook.

If I manually delete the "Mon " or use the replace all within the worksheet itself, I get the correct value of "dd/mm/yyyy" (converted to date format automatically). Serial number of the date 01/05/2015 for example being 42186.

However, when I use a macro to remove the "Mon " through the replace tool, the value of my dates changes to 05/01/2015. It is not a formatting error, but the actual value changing, new date serial number being 42009.

Any help as to why this is happening/how to stop it would be greatly appreciated!

I have included my macro replace code below.

```
Sub replace()
'Replace "Wed -Fri " with ""
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.replace What:="Wed ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.replace What:="Fri ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.replace What:="Thu ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

End Sub

Comment: What is the original format of column C before replacing? Is it formatted as text or date?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Range.Replace function in VBA will automatically convert the date to the default format of mm/dd/yyyy unless you override it. You should first try setting the formatting for Column C to Custom-> dd/mm/yyyy.

Adding this line to your VBA Sub right below `Columns("C:C").Select` will effectively do the same thing: `Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"`

For this issue though, I would probably just avoid VBA altogether and use something like `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-4)` assuming cell A1 contains `Mon 01/05/2015`

This would grab all characters in the cell except for the first 4. This of course requires data integrity where all days have only three letters and all have a space between the day and the date.

Comment: Another thing that should be noted is that the original format you referenced is a perfectly valid date format in excel. The custom date code would equal ddd dd/mm/yyyy. As such you may be able to accomplish everything using native excel date functionality.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew L, I didn't even think of using RIGHT and LEN. It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because, the system Regional format is in mm/dd/yyyy format, what you have to do is, after replacing the text, you should format the date to "dd/mm/yyyy" format